# Is comtypes compatible with Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, comtypes

Is comtypes compatible with Python3?
(I assume "no", but would like confirmation as it isn't written anywhere explicitly)

Additionally, any idea what would be closest replacement for comtypes on python3?

Comment: The metadata includes Python :: 3, so do you have a reason to think it isn't?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes. See https://pypi.org/project/comtypes/#files comtypes-1.1.4.zip. In `comtypes\__init__.py` at line 1026 there is `class helpstring(unicode):`. Type `unicode` is not available in python3, which makes this particular file incompatible with python3. What am I missing? (is there some "comptypes-python-3-version" which I am not able to find?)

Comment: That would be the name of an argument, which can be any valid identifier – it's not referring to the Python 2 builtin called `unicode`.

Comment: @koniiiik, it is name of parent class. (not an argument in function definition)

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. I must have misread it the first time around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in [`setup.py`](https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/blob/master/setup.py#L11). `comtypes` uses `2to3` to achieve Python 3 compatibility.